# Padding inside TextView with constraintWidth_max

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, textview, android-constraintlayout

I have a `TextView` inside of a constraint layout that I use for the layout of my items inside of a `RecyclerView`. Some strange behavior is going on. When the app first starts the width is correct but when I scroll up and back down then the width of the TextView has changed and is now padding the extra space.

## Code

```xml
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
        android:background="#C3C3C3"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_max="wrap"
        tools:text="hello there" />
```

## Original:

[image: original]

## After Scrolling:

[image: after scrolling]

Is there a reason for this behavior, and how can it be fixed to the expected one?

Comment: Did you try the Layout Inspector? Maybe you will spot some difference with it after scrolling. https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/layout-inspector

Comment: @einUsername I did but couldn't figure it out with that either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by replacing the wrapping the `TextView` with a `LinearLayout`. Not entirely sure why it didn't work the first time though.

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="80dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="64dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMessageBody"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#C3C3C3"
            tools:text="hello there" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be `android:layout_width="0dp"` causing problem or some extras margin.

Try this , I have removed extras margin ..

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#C3C3C3"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        tools:text="hello there" />
```

Comment: Thanks, that didn't really work for me though. I did post a community wiki answer with what worked